# On representing linear transformations as matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

**Question**

Suppose $V$ is the vector space of polynomials of degree $\leq 3$ and $T : V \to V$ is given by $$T[f(x)] = 2f(x) + 3f'(x).$$

Find a suitable basis for $V$ and compute the matrix representing $T$.

**My working**

I am likely going to tutor a course in linear algebra in the coming semester, so I am brushing up on my concepts right now, which are a little rusty as I last touched linear algebra more than three years ago.

I was able to find a basis for $V$, but I seem to have completely forgotten how to represent $T$.

We know that a generating set for the image of $T$ is the image of the standard basis of $V$, so a suitable basis of $V$ is
$$span\{T(1), T(x), T(x^2), T(x^3)\} = span\{2, 2x + 3, 2x^2 + 6x, 2x^3 + 9x^2\}.$$

Any help with finding $T$ will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the same ordered basis $\mathcal{B} = \{1,x,x^{2}x^{3}\}$ for the domain and counter-domain of the linear transformation $T$, you can set up its matricial representation as follows:
\begin{align*}
[T]_{\mathcal{B}} =
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 3 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 6 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2 & 9\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!